# Forcing: to find strictly stronger or weakly stronger condition?

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, forcing

In the $(*)$ below, I would like to understand whether "all we have to do is find $q>p$ such that ..."
or as I would say $q\geq p$ such that...

I have two questions about this: does this make any difference whether we are looking for such $q>p$
**or** $q\geq p$ and whether we can w.l.o.g. look for $q\geq p$.
Please note the opposite notion of **stronger than** in Shelah conception of forcing.

[image]

Comment: No, since there are no atoms, you can always strengthen a condition.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Please, where have you taken that assumption from that there are no atoms ?

Comment: It's not an assumption, $P$ is defined explicitly.

Comment: @AsafKaragila An atom in a poset $P$ with least element $0$, is by definition an element that is minimal among all elements that are unequal to $0$. So how it follows that we can always strengthen a condition ?

Comment: No, that is the case when you are forcing with a Boolean algebra. In the context of forcing, with the Jerusalem convention of "stronger is larger", an atom is a maximal condition (modulo the separativity quotient, of course).